# Is it possible to add network WebSphere server to eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere

I would like to add  network server to local eclipse if possible..So that hot deployment will work fine..

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I've always used Rational Application Developer which comes with this support built-in.  From playing around some, I've found this is not the case for Eclipse.  I found that you need to do two things before you can deploy applications to a remote WebSphere Application Server with Eclipse:

1. Install the WebSphere Developer Tools for Eclipse
2. Install a WebSphere Application Server instance on your local workstation (you don't need a profile)

Here is information on how to add WDT to Eclipse: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/was_beta_devtools/com.ibm.websphere.wdt.doc/topics/t_install_wdt_sdk.htm

In summary:

1. Go to the Eclipse marketplace: Help > Eclipse Marketplace...
2. Enter 'wdt' in the find field
3. Search for the WDT that matches your partner.  For instance, I'm using Eclipse Oxygen and WAS 8.5, so I chose **IBM WebSphere Application Server V8.5x Developer Tools for Oxygen**
4. Click Install

After you've installed WDT that matches your partner application server, you have to go one step farther and also install WebSphere on the local machine.  Why, I don't know.  It won't create the remote server if you don't do that.  When installing WebSphere, be sure that the Java version that you install matches the Java version that you have installed on your partner.

After you have installed WDT into Eclipse and WebSphere onto your workstation, to add the remote application server, do the following in your eclipse workspace:

1. Window > Show view > servers
2. Right click in the servers pane > New > Server
3. Expand IBM, then select the WebSphere application server version that matches your partner server (for example, WebSphere Application Server traditional V8.5)
4. In the server's hostname field, enter the fully-qualified hostname or ipaddress of your remote server machine.
5. Click Next
6. For installation directory, enter the fully-qualified name for your local application server directory.  For example, c:\was85512_base\WebSphere\AppServer
7. Click Next
8. Check RMI and SOAP and enter your RMI and SOAP ports
9. If security is enabled on your server, check the 'Security is enabled on this server' box, then enter your admin username and password.
10. Click Next
11. Fill out this next page as you like. (I always uncheck the 'Enable the server to start remotely' box because I don't like letting Eclipse control my app server)
12. Click Finish

I was able to do this using Eclipse Oxygen.  I have Indigo, Juno, Kepler, Luna, and Neon.  I started with one of those (I can't remember which; probably an old one) and I was unable to get the WDT installed.  I got the WDT installed on another one, but I wasn't having success, but that was before I figured out that you absolutely had to have a local WAS image.

Besides my move to Oxygen, I ran into the following problems:

1. I put on a WebSphere install image with the wrong Java version.  I had to install another one and create a new server runtime.
2. **java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=wsx6, OU=Root Certificate, OU=wsx6Cell, OU=wsx6Node is not trusted; internal cause is:, java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error**.  This is bananas because this is a self-signed certificate.  I went back and checked the server definition and **security is enabled on this server** was somehow unchecked.  I re-checked it and made sure that **automatically trust server certificate during SSL handshake** was checked.

If you mess up, you can create new WebSphere runtime environments in Eclipse:

1. Window > Preferences > Runtime Environments > Add > IBM
2. Choose the Application Server version.  You should have one listed for each WDT you have installed.
3. Enter your local installation directory (so Eclipse can find tools)
4. Finish

If you have more than one WebSphere runtime environment, make sure that you choose the correct matching one when creating your remote server.

I've used remote application servers in an assembly tool for a long time; I understand the appeal of it.  I like to do it because it keeps the memory-intensive application server off of the Eclipse machine.  Deploying apps is way faster this way.